# Name Error Pumpkin Project

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

I am currently having an issue with a project for my CS125 course. The premise of the project is to write a program that asks the user how many pumpkin weights they have, and then read that many pumpkin weights, printing each weight with a comment **Heavy, Normal, or Light**. The program must then average the weights and display them with three decimal places. The focus of the program is to use multiple functions rather than just one main function, which is where I am starting to have trouble. I believe I have the program just about complete, but I am getting a name error near the end. Here is the code so far:

```
# File: weights.py
# Date: 10/25/2017
# Author: Marcus Kassab
# Purpose: Print the average weight of a given number of pumpkins

def intro():
    print()
    print("Program to calculate the average of a")
    print("group of pumpkin weights.")
    print("You will be asked to enter the number of")
    print("pumpkins, followed by each pumpkin weight.")
    print("Written by Marcus Kassab.")
    print()

def getPumpkins():
    numPumpkins = int(input("Enter the number of pumpkins: "))
    print() #for turnin
    #print()
    totalWeight = 0
    count = 0
    for pumpkins in range(numPumpkins):
        count = count + 1
        pumpkinWeight = int(input("Enter the weight for pumpkin " + str(count) +": "))
        #print() #for turnin
        totalWeight = totalWeight + pumpkinWeight

        if pumpkinWeight >= 70:
            print("{0:0.3f}".format(pumpkinWeight), "is heavy.")
        elif pumpkinWeight >= 50 and pumpkinWeight < 70:
            print("{0:0.3f}".format(pumpkinWeight), "is normal.")
        else:
            print("{0:0.3f}".format(pumpkinWeight), "is light.")

    return numPumpkins, totalWeight

def calcAverage(totalWeight, numPumpkins):
    avg = float(totalWeight) / float(numPumpkins)
    print("The average weight of the", numPumpkins, "pumpkins is, "{0:0.3f}".format(avg))

def main():
    intro()
    getPumpkins()
    calcAverage(totalWeight, numPumpkins)

main()
```

When I run the program, it works fine up until it gets to calcAverage, where I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/marcuskassab/Documents/Courses 2017-18/CS 125/Projects/weights.py", line 45, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/marcuskassab/Documents/Courses 2017-18/CS 125/Projects/weights.py", line 43, in main
calcAverage(totalWeight, numPumpkins)
NameError: name 'totalWeight' is not defined
```

I'm not sure where the error lies, as I thought defining totalWeight in getPumpkins() would work. However, somewhere in calcAverage it seems to not be working. Any assistance with this error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: get the return values from the function call `numPumpkins, totalWeight = getPumpkins()`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning variables from `getPumpkins()` in `main()`, but you are not storing them anywhere before you try to use them on the next line for `calcAverage(totalWeight, numPumpkins)`.

Answer (score 0):

`getPumpkins()` is returning a tuple to `main` and you are not assigning it to anything. Change the following line in `main()`

```
numPumpkins, totalWeight = getPumpkins()
```